# TexWorks 'Library' Modules

Tags: texworks

I'm learning the official document of the texWorks script.

I saw a way to use the library as below the picture, 
but I could not find these files everywhere. Someone, could tells me where I can find them? Thank you very much
[image: wor]

Comment: which files? the `.mod` and `.js` files? they're in the next few pages of that documentation

Comment: @Troy  I've found `helper_PhpJs.mod,helper_twPan.mod,mod_general.js,mod_reload.js`;  But I still can't find `phpjs.namespaced.mod`. It references the URL "http://phpjs.org" is cannot reach

Comment: [php.js is Dead - Long Live Locutus](http://locutus.io/2016/05/announcing-locutus/) That document was based on info about 7 years ago so I will link you back exactly seven years via **\delorian{Jan 2012}**. However For the latest info you will need to go **back to the future in 2013 etc**. via the timeline at the top so press this button [http://phpjs.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103092137/http://phpjs.org)

Comment: see also https://github.com/kvz/locutus/commit/18e21b2301f130b89a22f8f35ec59466c5c840d7

Comment: @KJO you are so nice and I owe you my best thanks